# Can't find object when use Mongoid vs RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Have some strange problem when use Mongoid

I have the method in my controller:

```
def show
  @artist = Artist.find(params[:id])
  @albums = @artist.albums
end
```

And when I debuggin it i have result:

```
(byebug) Artist.find(params[:id])
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | test_taskv1_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"artists", "filter"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('574eea06ca418b3348657ea3')}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | test_taskv1_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.007681416999999999s
#<Artist _id: 574eea06ca418b3348657ea3, name: "Muse", itunes_id: 1093360>
(byebug) @artist
nil
```

So, `Artist.find(params[:id])` have a value what I need, but @artist is nil.
I do not understand how it happens. Maybe I missed something in mongoid documentation.
Sorry for my english

Comment: In your bybug session, you are not assigning the result of your `Artist.find` call to `@artist`.

Comment: @Holger if i write artist = Artist.find(params..) in byebug,  next artist will be work here. But in app it's nil. I can't use artist in second row and further.